# Jenkins job failed to copy files to MS Azure storage

Tags: jenkins, azure-storage

I'm really rare asking questions here, but last two days I'm fighting with an issue I never saw before.
Here is my problem:
I'm QA automation tester. My automation tests running on our QA server with Jenkins. When all tests finished.
I have another job to copy automation report with test results, to our Microsoft Azure storage, where our team can view automation result every morning.
Everything was fine, before yesterday. But now Jenkins job always failing to copy last 3 files of automation reports.
For Example, if I have 1000 files to copy, it will copy 997.
If I have 10 files to copy, it will copy 7 files, then it fail.
ALWAYS LAST 3 FILES[image]
We updates Jenkins plugins recently, I think its possible issue, but I'm not so good with Jenkins.
If you need any additional info, let me know. Thank you!

```
    D:/jenkins/workspace/HillsPRO/HillsPro-UI-Tests/hillspro-ui-automation/target/site/serenity/results.csv D:/jenkins/workspace/HillsPRO/HillsPro-UI-Tests/hillspro-ui-automation/target/site/serenity/scripts D:/jenkins/workspace/HillsPRO/HillsPro-UI-Tests/hillspro-ui-automation/target/site/serenity/serenity-resources D:/jenkins/workspace/HillsPRO/HillsPro-UI-Tests/hillspro-ui-automation/target/site/serenity/summary.txt 'D:\Jenkins\workspace\HillsPRO\aq.hillspro/02_17_2022/Serenity'
ERROR: AzureStorage - Error occurred while uploading to Azure - vmlnaaqreports
com.microsoftopentechnologies.windowsazurestorage.exceptions.WAStorageException: Only 1369/1372 files are successfully uploaded.
    at com.microsoftopentechnologies.windowsazurestorage.service.UploadService.execute(UploadService.java:563)
    at com.microsoftopentechnologies.windowsazurestorage.WAStoragePublisher.perform(WAStoragePublisher.java:472)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:78)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$2.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:33)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:806)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:755)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:178)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:699)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1913)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:99)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:432)
ERROR: Step ‘Upload artifacts to Azure Storage’ aborted due to exception: 
com.microsoftopentechnologies.windowsazurestorage.exceptions.WAStorageException: Only 1369/1372 files are successfully uploaded.
    at com.microsoftopentechnologies.windowsazurestorage.service.UploadService.execute(UploadService.java:563)
    at com.microsoftopentechnologies.windowsazurestorage.WAStoragePublisher.perform(WAStoragePublisher.java:472)
Caused: java.io.IOException: AzureStorage - Error occurred while uploading to Azure - vmlnaaqreports
    at com.microsoftopentechnologies.windowsazurestorage.WAStoragePublisher.perform(WAStoragePublisher.java:502)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:78)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$2.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:33)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:806)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:755)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:178)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:699)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1913)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:99)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:432)
Started calculate disk usage of build
Finished Calculation of disk usage of build in 0 seconds
Started calculate disk usage of workspace
Finished Calculation of disk usage of workspace in 0 seconds
[WS-CLEANUP] Deleting project workspace...
[WS-CLEANUP] Deferred wipeout is used...
[WS-CLEANUP] done
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Hello @IPolnik,Can you please let me know what is the version of Jenkins you are using?

Comment: Hello @RahulKumarShaw-MT, thank you for reply. I did a research, and seems that problem is not on my side. there is some issue with Jenkins Azure plugin https://github.com/jenkinsci/azure-storage-plugin/issues/209. I'm just waiting when its will be fixed. Thank you.

Comment: Yes Correct, The issue is with Azure Plugins, They are under maintance as of now so this could be reason you are facing difficulties to Upload Large File. Even the Same kind of issue we are expericing with Azure App Service, Azure Cosmos ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested in My enviroment facing the same kind of issue. This is because many Azure plugin is under maintaince by ***Jenkins Community team*** as of now this may took time as per Document from ***Jenkins Portal***.Currently Showing This Status.

[image]

***Reference : https://plugins.jenkins.io/windows-azure-storage/***